# Updating multiple rows with different values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I got this table in my MySQL database, 'users'. It has the fields 'id' and 'value'.

Now, I want to update *lots of* rows in this table with a *single* SQL query, but many rows should get a different value. Currently, I'm using this:

```
UPDATE users
    SET value = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 53
        WHEN 2 THEN 65
        WHEN 3 THEN 47
        WHEN 4 THEN 53
        WHEN 5 THEN 47
    END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

This works. But I feel I could do some optimization since there are only about 3 or 4 different values I'm assigning to the rows. As you can see, right now these are 47, 53 and 65. Is there a way I can update all rows that get the same value simultaneously within the same query? Or, is there another way I can optimize this?

Comment: You could store the mapping in a separate table and join to it.

Comment: @Pointy: why not put this as an answer?

Comment: @Benoit because while I know SQL, I don't know MySQL and therefore would not necessarily be able to construct a correct example.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rather than doing `case variable when value then ...`, try doing `case when condition then ...` - like so:

```
UPDATE users
    SET value = CASE 
        WHEN id in (1,4) THEN 53
        WHEN id = 2 THEN 65
        WHEN id in (3,5) THEN 47
    END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 12):

Assuming id is unique or primary...

```
insert into users 
  (id,value) 
VALUES 
  (1,53),(2,65),(3,47),(4,53),(5,47)
on duplicate key update
value=VALUES(value)
```

Comment: I don't know why this got so few votes. It's perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I would just do this with a few different UPDATE statements.

```
UPDATE users
    SET value = 53
WHERE id = 1;


UPDATE users
    SET value = 65
WHERE id = 2;

...
```

This seems simplest if you only have 5 or 6 values to set on multiple rows each.  Or is there some specific reason that you need to do this in one query?