# Mysql Update mutiple row of datas

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know how to efficiently update multiple rows of data with the `UPDATE` statement. I know I can insert multiple records like this one below.

```
INSERT INTO example
  (example_id, name, value, other_value)
VALUES
  (100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'),
  (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
  (102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'),
  (103, 'Name 4', 'Value 4', 'Other 4');
```

But how it works in Update, or if I have to loop the query and update one by one?

At the moment I have to use `foreach` to loop and update each `SQL` statement.

```
foreach() {
    // update statement....
    // and execute the query
}
```

Comment: just use the `WHERE` clause

Comment: Updating multiple rows can be way shorter than insert but at the same time be very dangerous if proper conditions are not supplied.  What is it that you are trying to solve, can you add that to the question, hopefully some sample data and some conditions?

Comment: Do you wanna use different value in each one or update wuth the same value ?

Comment: @vinodadhikary Thanks yes there is condition. i have associated id attach with it

Comment: @AlphaRootMks yes different value

Comment: You can use `LOAD SQL LOCAL INFILE` type of update but it gets complicated especially when dealing with updating data and not simply appending rows to a table. We'd have to see your table design for any further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use case when indise update..

An eg:

```
UPDATE users
    SET value = CASE 
        WHEN id in (1,4) THEN 53
        WHEN id = 2 THEN 65
        WHEN id in (3,5) THEN 47
    END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Refer this [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882388/updating-multiple-rows-with-different-values) and [this](http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/) for more.

Comment: nice this is what i am after.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $data = array(
    array(
        100, 
        'Name 1',
        'Value 1', 
        'Other 1'
    ),
    array(
        101, 
        'Name 2', 
        'Value 2', 
        'Other 2',
    )
    array(
        102, 
        'Name 3', 
        'Value 3',
        'Other 3'
    )
```

)

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {

for($j= 0; $j< count($data[$i]); $j++) {
    $field1 = $data[$i][$j];
    $field2 = $data[$i][$j];
    $filed3 = $data[$i][$j];
    $field4 = $data[$i][$j];
        query("UPDATE TABLE SET.... WHERE id = $field1");

}
}
```

Comment: That's insert RPM I want update. Thanks any how and this not efficiently, look at my insert above

Comment: @bluebill1049 see my update -- i've wrote a Pseudo-query showing you how you would do it;

Comment: Thank RPM give u a "UP" anyhow @Pra answer is what i am after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CASE** in **MYSQL** also:

Ex:

```
UPDATE example
    SET example_id = CASE 
        WHEN example_id=100 THEN 1000
        WHEN example_id=101 THEN 1001
        WHEN example_id=102 THEN 1002
        ELSE example_id*10
    END
```

You can see another example, In this, there is a table `Person` and having wrongly entered `Gender`. So you need to correct them by updating `Male to Female` and `Female to Male`.

So here is your code:

```
UPDATE Person 
    SET Gender= CASE
        WHEN gender= 'Male' THEN 'Female' 
        WHEN gender= 'Female' THEN 'Male' 
        ELSE gender 
    END
```